# How should I write unit tests for multiple implementations of an interface, while adhering to DRY?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dry

I have multiple classes that implement the same interface, how should I write unit tests to verify that each class implements the interface correctly, keeping code duplication to a minimum (DRY)?

As an example of what I mean, the following is a very basic library containing two implementations of `IDeleter`: `Deleter1` and `Deleter2`. Both implement the method `Delete` by calling `Delete` on their associated `IRepository`.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace TestMultiple
{
    public interface IRepository
    {
        void Delete(string id);
    }

    public abstract class Baseclass
    {
        protected abstract IRepository GenericRepository { get; }

        public void Delete(string id)
        {
            GenericRepository.Delete(id);
        }
    }

    public interface IDeleter
    {
        void Delete(string id);
    }

    public interface IRepository1 : IRepository
    {
    }

    public abstract class RepositoryBase
    {
        public void Delete(string id)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Repository1 : RepositoryBase, IRepository1
    {
    }

    public class Deleter1 : Baseclass, IDeleter
    {
        protected override IRepository GenericRepository { get { return Repository; } }

        [Dependency]
        public IRepository1 Repository { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRepository2 : IRepository
    {
    }

    public class Repository2 : RepositoryBase, IRepository2
    {
    }

    public class Deleter2 : Baseclass, IDeleter
    {
        protected override IRepository GenericRepository { get { return Repository; } }

        [Dependency]
        public IRepository2 Repository { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For these two classes, `Deleter1` and `Deleter2`, I have written two corresponding unit test classes as shown in the below snippet. The tests check the same behaviour, i.e. that `Delete` is called on the underlying repository. Is there some better way to implement the same tests for all implementations of `IDeleter`? For example, should I write a baseclass containing common test methods, such as `TestDelete`, for `TestDeleter1` and `TestDeleter2`?

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Moq;

namespace TestMultiple.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestDeleter1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestDelete()
        {
            var mockRepo = new Mock<IRepository1>();
            var container = new UnityContainer().RegisterInstance<IRepository1>(mockRepo.Object);
            var deleter = container.Resolve<Deleter1>();
            deleter.Delete("id");
            mockRepo.Verify(r => r.Delete("id"));
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class TestDeleter2
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestDelete()
        {
            var mockRepo = new Mock<IRepository2>();
            var container = new UnityContainer().RegisterInstance<IRepository2>(mockRepo.Object);
            var deleter = container.Resolve<Deleter2>();
            deleter.Delete("id");
            mockRepo.Verify(r => r.Delete("id"));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Feel free to mention unit test frameworks that may help solve this kind of problem, although my preference is with NUnit.

Comment: Inheritance? Create a base class with all of the commonality inside, then derive from it for each concrete type needing testing (different test frameworks may make this easier or not)

Comment: (And just to be clear, I was suggesting inheritance in the test classes, not necessarily in the implementations)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's one approach I considered. I have been doing this in Python, but in that language I believe there were some problems (tests being picked up for the test baseclass, not each subclass IIRC). Would you mind writing your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no easy way to write tests in the frameworks I'm aware of that assert common behaviour on interfaces. The best you can do is write tests and helper methods as if you were testing an abstract class and then insert the real type into derived test classes.

For example, you could create an `DeleterTests` class, which provides tests for the interface:

```
public abstract class DeleterTests<TRepository> where TRepository : IRepository
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDelete()
    {
        var mockRepo = new Mock<TRepository>();
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterInstance<TRepository>(mockRepo.Object);

        var deleter = this.CreateDeleter(container);

        deleter.Delete("id");
        mockRepo.Verify(r => r.Delete("id"));
    }

    protected abstract IDeleter CreateDeleter(IUnityContainer container);
}
```

Then, you inherit from this class for anything implementing `IDeleter`, implementing the abstract `CreateDeleter` method as you need to:

```
public class Deleter1Tests : DeleterTests<IRepository1>
{
    protected override IDeleter CreateDeleter(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return container.Resolve<Deleter1>();
    }
}

public class Deleter2Tests: DeleterTests<IRepository2>
{
    protected override IDeleter CreateDeleter(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return container.Resolve<Deleter2>();
    }
}
```

If you needed to compose the instances differently, you could implement the abstract `CreateDeleter` in any fashion.

Comment: Hmm just fyi I couldnt immediately get this to work in VS2013, as the tests would never be discovered using this tecnique.

Answer (score 1):

You should write unit test for each class, not really worrying about other implementations. If you feel like you write the same tests again and again, it is propably because your production code is un-DRY -- not your test code. As others have pointed out; if the different implementations have a lot in comon, some common abstract ancestor is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your classes should implement the IDeleter interface identically, your base class should not be abstract. Implement the IDeleter interface in the base class, that way all of the child classes inherit the same implementation from the base. If there is an edge case where a different implementation is desired, that class can then override the base class' implementation.

Comment: IMHO an abstract base class is a better approach.  There are people you believe that base classes should be abstract and concrete classes sealed. Scott Meyers and the designers of .NET (see section 6.2 of Framework Design Guidelines Second Edition by Cwalina and Abrams) are among them.

Comment: It's certainly a possibility to do make the baseclass do almost everything and test that, but for this problem let's assume I wish to test each implementation directly instead of the baseclass?

Comment: @Panos - I don't believe that I should be pidgeonholed into some language purists idea of how to best write code (even if they work for Microsoft), I believe in using the best tool/technique for the job.

Comment: @aknuds1, if that is the case, I really don't know of a better approach than what you are already using. If the implementations are separate and distinct, then they will have to be tested individually.

Comment: @Kevin How about Damien_The_Unbeliever's suggestion though, i.e. to write test methods in a baseclass?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me to use inheritance in the test classes to ensure that all implementations of the IDeleter interface are tested the same. It will have the side-effect of eliminating "wrong" implementations in the test classes from typing/pasting the code in many places.